# Get Query Params in IE 11

Tags: javascript

This function errors out in IE 11 but works with other browsers. I expect params to be something like `params = {user: 123}` if URL is `http://example.com/?user=123`.

```
let params = {};
window.location.href.replace(
    /[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
    (_, key, value) => (params[key] = value)
);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It's an React app so most of the files don't run properly. The errors I'm getting is `syntax error 0.chunk.js` and `expected identifier main.chunk.js`.

Comment: Fat arrow functions aren't supported in IE

Comment: Phix' comment says it all — https://caniuse.com/#search=arrow

Comment: @Phix MY HERO..

Answer (score 5):

Because IE 11 does not support the arrow function syntax, you have to<sup>[1]</sup> replace that code with the equivalent that has an explicit callback function

```
var params = {};
window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
    function(_, key, value) {
        return params[key] = value;
    });
```

As griest mentions in a comment, to be safe you should use [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) on the href, so that line becomes

```
decodeURIComponent(window.location.href).replace(/..etc../,
```

<sub>[1] "have to", unless you are in the fortunate position of just declaring that you don't support Internet Explorer.</sub>

Comment: I'd like to add that the keyword `let` does not exist in IE11, and only `var` can be used instead.

Comment: To be safe you should use `decodeURIComponent(value)`

Answer (score -6):

Try this one:

```
var params = new URLSearchParams(url)
params.get(name)
```

Comment: This `URLSearchParams ` does not work in `IE`. Just for your information

Comment: OP is also not simply trying to get the values of the parameters, they are trying to transform the URL.

Comment: Downvoting, as this doesn't work in IE at all.